# return value in Try Catch with generics

Tags: c#, generics, try-catch

I'm having a problem specifying the proper return value in a `try/catch` block.
I'm novice level scripter and have never used generics before.

The error message is:

> *"An object of type convertible to `T` is required"*

What specifically do I need to return at the end of my `try/catch`?

```
private static T LoadData<T>(string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<T>(File.ReadAllText(filePath));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // Something went wrong, so lets get information about it.
        Debug.Log(e.ToString());
        return ?????;
    }
}
```

Comment: The only sensible thing is to rethrow the exception. Or `return default;` I recommend the former.

Comment: I suggest to rethrow the exception: `throw;` instead of any kind of `return`

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the application behaviour that you want to define. You can have it return a `new T()` / `default` (I wouldn't advise this as users cant tell if the operation was successful or not) or you can throw the exception up a level so that it can be handled else where. The whole point of a try catch is to handle unexpected *specific* behaviour, thus its not a good idea to catch generic exceptions unless you have a generic way of handling it.

Comment: Note that to return `new T()` you have to constrain `T` to have a parameterless constructor (`where T:new()`)

Comment: @DStanley Sorry I didn't literally mean `new T()`, in my head I envisioned using `Activator` to instantiate the object but yes, you are correct.

Comment: Code samples of the two options would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

When *something* went wrong we can't just *ignore* it; if we don't have enough information to make a decision, a best option is to escalate the problem: may be a top level method knows what to do.

So I suggest to *rethrow* the  exception instead of *returning* any value:

```
private static T LoadData<T>(string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<T>(File.ReadAllText(filePath));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // Something went wrong, so lets get information about it.
        Debug.Log(e.ToString());
        
        // let top level method decide what to do:
        //   1. Do nothing (just ignore the exception)
        //   2. Do something (e.g. change permission) with filePath
        //   3. Try load from some other file
        //   4. Try load from some other source, say RDBMS
        //   5. Use some default value
        //   6. Close the application
        //   7. ....    
        throw;
    }
}
```

Please note, that here, within `LoadData<T>` method we don't know the context, and that's why we can't decide which option from `1..7` is the best one